# Scrappy outputs the data column by column, I want to scrape row by row. How is it possible?

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

Below is the code and Picture for spider is shown below:

```
def parse_getData(self, response):
    rows=response.xpath('//*[@id="table-timetable"]/table/tbody')
    items=[]
    for row in rows:
        item = ScraperItem()
        item['Day'] = row.xpath('.//tr/th/strong/text()').extract() 
        item['Time'] = row.xpath('.//td/span[1]/text()').extract()
        item['Venue']=row.xpath('.//td/span[3]/text()').extract()
        item['Subject']=row.xpath('.//td/strong/text()').extract()                   
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

[image: It outputs the data for the Day together and then moves to Subject.]

I want it to out the result as below:

`{'Day':Monday 'Subject':u'BIS3208 (L) - SEMINAR SERIES',u'NET3204 (P) - DISTRIBUTED SYSTEMS'}`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not Scrapy, but how you create your items. You have to change the xpath queries accordingly and select the text that you need each time. Right now you are selecting all the text.

EDIT

For the sake of clarification.

```
row.xpath('.//tr/th/strong/text()').extract()
```

A query like this selects all the tr elements in the document and then the th children, resulting in not only one element as you need for filling your Scrapy item. You have to process the elements retrieved with your xpath query accordingly and use that data to create your Scrapy item. There is not other way Scrapy can know about it automatically.

Comment: changing the xpaths worked for me since i am aware of how many rows i have to scrape and i have the xpath for each row. But what about the programs who does not know many rows it has to deal with and dont have xpath for them, in such program we cant hardcode the xpath. What should we do in such situations?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem here: "But what about the programs who does not know many rows it has to deal with and dont have xpath for them". Do you mean in case the web content is generated dynamically?

Comment: i mean, i my case i knew i had to scrap 7 rows, so i just took the xpath of those seven rows separately and the result was in format, 
Row1: Col1, Col2, Col3. But what if a scraper scrapes 100s of row, then we cannot take 100 xpaths separately in order to get the data in format Row1: Col1, Col2, Col3. Do you get what I am trying to say?

Comment: Ok, then in that case basically all you need to do is to process the text you get in the different columns and split it. You can always apply your own parsing code. Then iterate and feed the specific field of your Scrapy item accordingly. You see the point?

Comment: ohh i see, then its up to us how we design our program, we can use pipeline too then right? I thought maybe there must be some standard way of doing so. Thanks Alot!